# For loop in matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am new user with Matlab and I wrote this script. At the end I have to operate the formula written below. To the `y(j,:)` value, it gives me the right answer but when I use for loop a second time the value of `z(i,:)` gives me the wrong answer.I want element by element multiplication I checked answer by calculating it on calculator. Can someone look at this why I am getting wrong values for `z(i,:)`

```
% formula I(Q,t) = A exp(-t/tau_beta)^beta    

% beta
beta= [0.4 0.6 0.8 1];   
tau_beta = [1 10 100 1000];
t=[0:1:1e4];

% division of (t/tbeta)
for j= 1:1:4
    y(j,:) = t/tau_beta(j);
    for i = 1:1:4
        z(i,:) = y(j,:).^beta(i);
        A =1;
        I_temp(i,:) = A*exp(-z(i,:));
        I(i,j,:) = I_temp(i,:);
    end
end
```

Comment: What's the problem you're facing? what's the result you're getting and what are you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

```
z(i,:) = exp(-y(j,:)).^beta(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier to evaluate functions over some parameter space by using the functions `meshgrid` (for spaces consisting of 2 parameters) or `ndgrid` (for spaces of any dimensionality). These basically are a convenient way of doing the required `repmat`'s to create the space to evaluate your function over.

Use like so:

```
[bm,tbm,tm] = ndgrid(beta,tau_beta,t);
I = A*exp(-tm./tbm).^bm;
```

`ndgrid` creates matrices spanning the space of its input arguments, doing any calculations with these is like evaluating the function for all possible combinations of your input parameters.

Using `bsxfun` you can eliminate the extra memory used by first computing the grid, but it gets rather illegible quickly.

Comment: It means I don't need for loop but how it will go from 1:4

Comment: Because your inputs ``beta`` and ``tau_beta`` have length 4. ``ndgrid`` takes your input and replicates it to set up for evaluation of all possible combinations of input parameters, i.e., to evaluate your function over the space you defined with in this case ``beta``, ``tau_beta`` and ``t``. You can make any of these inputs any length (within memory constraints) and the ``ndgrid`` and function evaluation will automatically do the right thing.